# Creating an if statement in Joomla

Tags: if-statement, joomla

I've built a website using a purchased template and Joomla. I have a corporate logo which shows up perfectly on desktop. It comes up way too big on mobile. This is the following code I have entered.

```
<p><img src="images/Logomakr_7azv9e.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></p>
```

How would I write an if statement so that logo/picture only shows up on desktops and not mobile? Or perhaps to make the logo appear, just smaller?

Comment: Sounds like a CSS problem.

Comment: This is the code right now<p><img src="images/Logomakr_7azv9e.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" /></p>

Comment: Why are you hard coding rather than using CSS? An if statement is not the way to do this, proper use of the css in your template is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, CSS is the best way to do this.

**HTML**
Add a class to your image so you can target it and remove the height and width values:

```
<p><img class="logo" src="images/Logomakr_7azv9e.png" alt=""  /></p>
```

**CSS**

Set the default values for the size of the logo

```
.logo{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Use @media queries to hide the logo on mobile, adjust the viewport from 767px to whatever you prefer

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .logo{display:none;}
}
```

You do have other options though. You mention that the logo is too wide on mobile, so instead of removing it completely you could also make it smaller:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .logo{
    width:30%;
    height:30%;       
   }
 }
```

Good luck!